# How to identify Enter key in URL?

Tags: android, url, message, space, enter

I am making an android Application in this **URL is passing with the user define message.**

My URL is:

**[URL for fetching message](http://demo1.idevtechnolabs.com//smartecard/love/free/free.php?msg=Hi%20how%20r%20you%20dear)**

My problem is:
When user press space at that time the space can be Identified by 
**Space="%20"**
but what to do when user press enter key?

Is there any way to **identify that user had pressed enter key** in URL.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by `enter` key ?

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/23ce/index.htm

Comment: Enter key from keyboard

Comment: Did you tried with "\n" ?

Comment: Yes I had but I got printed \n character not enter

Comment: Can you paste your code ?

Comment: Its not about coding I Just making change in above url

Comment: hi @LuckyyNickey you can identify \n as a enter

Answer (score 8):

You can identify as

**Enter** or **NewLine** = `%0A` or `%0D` or `%0D%0A`

Comment: Hmmm it only return Space not enter

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Types%5Fof%5FURI%5Fcharacters See here

Comment: The ASCII device control characters %00-%1f were originally designed to control hardware devices. Control characters have nothing to do inside a URL.

Comment: @LuckyyNickey that is how the website is programmed, to convert any new line characters to %20

Comment: %20 is for space na dear?

Answer (score 0):

If the Enter key is pressed while the user is typing the message, a newline `\n` will be created. When passed to a URL, newline character will be url encoded as `%0A`. So check your URL for `%0A` and if you can't find it in the URL, then probably the user didn't press enter while typing the message.

Answer (score 0):

Enter = %0D%0A

Enter or NewLine =
%0A
or
%0D
or
%0D%0A